# How to add hyperlinks to a terminal [ Node.js ]

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal

I am looking to add a hyperlink within my terminal output using `process.stdout.write()` which is just a `console.log()` with a line break (`\n`) at the end of it. 
 
What I have attempted so far:

- ```sh
  console.log(`\e]8;;http://example.com\aThis is a hyperlink\e]8;;\a`);
  ```
- ```sh
  process.stdout.write(`[This is a hyperlink](http://example.com)`);
  ```

Although the outputs remain undiffered from the whole string printing into my console.

[Possible Duplicate Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509109/how-to-give-url-in-shell-script/509156) - Does not answer my question

Comment: Thats nothing you can control. Its handled by the terminal and not you. In Bash for example, hold shift & left mouse klick opens the link. There is nothing you can do about it. Just print out the url `http://example.com` and your are ready to go.

Comment: Although the URL is too long and I don't wanna add it as a whole, passing it through a URL shortener is not a choice as it would simply look shady since it's a sensitive URL so I need it to maintain it's original form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fully-featured terminal interfaces who can achieve this goal. But in general most terminal interfaces are [Dumb Terminals](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3032/dumb-terminal), and don't support clickable hyperlinks.

The new [Windows 1.4 Terminal](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-terminal-14-released-with-hyperlink-and-jump-list-support/) will support hyperlinks, but it will release together with Windows 11.

A well documented Fully-Featured terminal is [GNOME](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/).

```
echo -e '\e]8;;http://example.com\aThis is a hyperlink\e]8;;\a'
```

This is a code snippet if how to do to it in gnome, once you ctrl + Click it, the hyperlink will redirect you to your desired page.

Comment: I see, so the windows terminal actually does not support hyperlinks yet?

Comment: The current version of Windows terminal doesn't support it. But you can install windows terminal 1.4 Preview on your local machine. https://www.microsoft.com/nl-be/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n8g5rfz9xk3?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab here is the windows store link :)